# SQL WHERE first 3 letters NOT IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query string:

```
declare @deadCommunityList table(community varchar(12))
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('000')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('253')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('COU')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('COV')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('D2T')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('D3T')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('DEW')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('DIT')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('E2T')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('E3T')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('EL2')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('EL3')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('ELC')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('ELI')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('ELT')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('ERI')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('FA1')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('GRA')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('GRD')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('GRT')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('HIG')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('HIP')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('LYN')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('NEW')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('PAR')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('PMT')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('RDT')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('RES')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('SCR')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('SCT')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('SMT')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('SUM')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('TB')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('W2T')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('WDV')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('WE2')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('WIC')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('WEC')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('WIL')
    insert into @deadCommunityList (community) values ('ZIT')

    SELECT Job_No FROM Schedule WHERE Job_No NOT IN (SELECT * FROM @deadCommunityList) ORDER BY Job_No
```

Now a Job_No would look like 253DEWT which would not match with 253 which means a row with Job_No 253DEWT will appear which I don't want it to, so what I am trying to do is compair the first 3 characters the to values in the deadCommunityList....what adjustments do I have to make?

Comment: Holy run-on sentence, Batman.  Why don't you take a deep breath and try that again.  Split your question up into proper sentences so we don't have to parse that painful mess.

Comment: I believe you are looking at Substring. Are you saying you want to only compare the 1st 3 characters?

Comment: 253DEWT which would not match with 253 ?  Did you really need to insert 20+ values to show the problem ?  And you can do values ( ),  ( ), ( )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To SELECT the first 3 letters from a column:

```
SELECT LEFT(column_name , 3) FROM table_name;
```

Alternatively you can use the `substring` function:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(column_name, 1, 3) FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
    job_no
FROM
    dbo.Schedule S
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM @deadCommunityList
        WHERE community = LEFT(S.job_no, 3)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

they are not all 3

```
SELECT s.job_no
  FROM dbo.Schedule S
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                      FROM @deadCommunityList
                     WHERE S.job_no like community + '%'
                  )
```